# Check the Health of Undertow deployed application using Http call java

Tags: java, undertow

As I have deployed my legacy application into Undertow server.
I need to create an endpoint to check the health of the server thrw Http.
We are having methods like
 `HTTPServer.server().restart()`.
Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you can use health check in your proxy like ngnix (see this documentation) :

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/

Comment: Hi The question was misleading, actually the aws architect want me to give any GET endpoints for his ALB.